# RegEx to match only a specific column with lookaround

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a **.CSV** which I'm handling in a large file editor (BssEditor):

```
DOC;NAME;A_TYPE;ADDRESS;NUMBER;COMPLEMENT;NEIGHBORHOOD;CITY;STATE;ZIPCODE
7971530;Obi Wan Kenobi;R;OF THE PITANGUEIRAS;0000731;;MATATU;DUBAI;BA;40255436
7971541;Anakim Skywalker;AV;VISCONDE OF JEQUITINHONHA;0000243;AP 601;GOOD VOYAGE;RECIFE;PE;51021190
7971974;Jabba the Hutt;;DOS ILHEUS;0000118;APT 600;CENTER;FLOWERPOLIS;SC;88010560
7972512;Mando;;JUNDIACANGA;0000037;HOUSE;IPAVA CITY;SAINT PAUL;SP;04950150
```

The column delimiter is **`;`**, and I wanna match all zeros in the beginning of the NUMBER column to replace with nothing.
Ex.: **<kbd>0000731</kbd>→<kbd>731</kbd>**

It's easy to match everything with `^((.*?;){4})0+` and replace by `$1`, but not with lookaround...
I tried RegEx like that

```
/^(?<=.*?;){4}0+/
/(?<=^.*?;.*?;.*?;.*?;)0+/
```

but it looks like the greedy wildcard only works within a lookahead, not a lookbehind.

There are a way?
And having a way, is there a performance issue when dealing with millions of entries?

Comment: What language are you using? Some support variable-length lookbehinds, others don't. Some languages don't support any lookarounds. Also, it's not clear that the use of a regex is appropriate here. You probably want to use CSV methods to extract field values. Some languages have ways of doing what you want within the CSV methods. You could also convert, say, `'0000731'` to an integer (`731`) and then convert the integer back to a string (`'731'`).

Comment: Well as I said .csv I thought it to be understood that I was using a large file editor... BssEditor that uses interpretation with MS flavor of regex handling. But I'm testing it on Notepad++

Comment: The fifth line has 5 zeros would you like it to be untouched? Or let it be changed to  `037`

Answer (score 2):

An infinite quantifier in a lookbehind is only supported by a few regex engines (.NET, Python PyPi module, newer Javascript like V8), but not in notepad++ which uses boost.

If you are using notepad++, you don't need lookarounds or capture groups. You could repeat semicolon separated parts until you get to the number column and use `\K` to clear the current match buffer.

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
^(?:[^;\n]*;){4}\K0+
```

- `^` start of string
- `(?:[^;\n]*;){4}` Repeat 4 times matching any char except ; or a newline, then match ;
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `0+` Match one or more times a zero

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fccbgn/1)

The capture group solution seems like a good solution, you could write it using a single capture group and use a negated character class instead of `.*?` to prevent some backtracking.

```
^((?:[^;\n]*;){4})0+
```

In the replacement use group 1, often notated as `$` or `\1`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P3Cwkl/1)

Comment: Nice. In years of using Regex I didn't know about \k.

Comment: Why are you negating `[^;\n]`? It works with `^(?:.*?;){4}\K0+` too. That way it looks clearer.

Comment: @Zano It works, but `.*?` introduces backtracking to match any character as least as possible. The negated character class matches any character except what is not allowed to match. You can see for example the amount of steps here for the non greedy pattern https://regex101.com/r/lyJ1RK/1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about BssEditor, but the following works in Notepad++

```js
(?<=;)0+(?=\d+;(?:[^;]*;){4}[^;]*?$)
```

A positive lookahead is used to only match if there are exactly five semicolons ahead in the string on that line.

> is there a performance issue when dealing with millions of entries?

Possibly.

Comment: Thx, it works well too. And lets a zero remaining in case of only 00000

Comment: What is the need to use `$`? Your code was what worked in BssEditor, but without anchor. As it is not good at handling EOL.

Comment: I see you are anchoring at the end of the line. I could replace it with \n in BssEditor. But why didn't you anchor at the beginning?

Comment: @Zano `$` (or `\n`) is needed otherwise a number from an earlier column may match because there will still be 5 semicolons ahead on the line. For example, without the anchor, the regex will mistakenly match if there are 7 semicolons ahead in the line. There is no need to anchor at the beginning.

Comment: Hi, I would like to add spaces in your expression so that it removes everything before [; \d]. So I made a series of columns that I filled with zeros and spaces to test. And I got it with the expression `(?<=;)[ 0]+(?=(\d+;|;)(?:[^;]*;){5,6}[^;]*?$)` . But interestingly, in Notepad++, several other columns flash green when searching. It doesn't select the wrong columns, but I'm afraid it can degrade performance. What do you think?